# Do i need additional Firebase SDK for Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

My app already has integrated Firebase SDK for Crashlytics.

Is that SDK sufficient for implementing Firebase Dynamic Links feature or will I require an additional/separate SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Firebase product comes with its own SDK. If you want to use Dynamic Links, you will have to include the specific SDK for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk), [C++](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/cpp/receive#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk), or [Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity/receive#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk). This is indeed in addition to the Crashlytics SDK you're already using.